# Can't edit initial textbox value with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm passing parameters from one page to the other with react native navigation. The value is able to pass alright, but the issue is when the value is in the textbox it can't be edited. You press a key and it deletes automatically leaving the initial value there.

View Container

```
const GroupDetailsEditScreen =({setGroupName, groupName, setDescription, description, onSelectImage, ImageSource, displayImage, onSaveEdits, showIndicator})=>(
      <View style={{padding:10, backgroundColor:'white', height:'100%'}}>

      <TextInput value={groupName} onChangeText={setGroupName} style={{marginBottom:10, backgroundColor:'#fafafa'}} mode="flat"  label='Group Name' autoCapitalize = 'none' />
      <TextInput value={description} onChangeText={setDescription} style={{marginBottom:10,backgroundColor:'#fafafa', height:150}} mode="flat" multiline={true} numberOfLines={3} label='Group Description' />
      <Button style={{height:55, margin:10, justifyContent:"center"}}
      icon="save" 
      mode="contained"
      color="#00aae0"
      uppercase="false"
      onPress={() => {onSaveEdits()}} >
    Save Edit
  </Button>

  <ActivityIndicator style={{padding:5, color:'white'}}
                animating={showIndicator}
                size="small"/>

     </View>
    )

export default GroupDetailsEditScreen;
```

Container Component

```
class GroupDetailsEditContainer extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = () => ({
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#00aae0'},
    headerTintColor: 'white'
  })

  state = {
    displayImage: false,
    showLoader : false
  };

  setGroupName = (newGroupName) => {
    this.setState({ newGroupName: newGroupName })
    }

  setDescription = (description) => {
    this.setState({ description: description })
    }


render() {
const { navigation } = this.props;
const getGroupID = navigation.getParam('groupID');
const getGroupName = navigation.getParam('groupName');
const getDescription =  navigation.getParam('description');
    return (
    <GroupDetailsEditScreen
      onHandleSelectedValue = {this.handleSelectedValue}
      onSelectImage = {this.handleSelectPhoto}
      ImageSource = {this.state.ImageSource}
      displayImage = {this.state.displayImage}
      setGroupName = {this.setGroupName}
      groupName =     {getGroupName}
      setDescription = {this.setDescription}
      description =  {getDescription}
      showIndicator = {this.state.showLoader}
      onSaveEdits = {this.handleSaveEdits}
    />
    );
  }
}

export default GroupDetailsEditContainer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the updated value from your parent component to the child one if it exist, and the default value if it does not so that the value is updated with the state :

```
<GroupDetailsEditScreen
    groupName ={this.state.newGroupName || getGroupName}
    description ={this.state.description || getDescription}
/>
```

I would recommend deconstructing your state to make it more readable like what you did with your props :

```
const { description, newGroupName } = this.state

<GroupDetailsEditScreen
    groupName ={newGroupName || getGroupName}
    description ={description || getDescription}
/>
```

You can also use the [`defaultValue`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#defaultvalue) prop of the `TextField` instead if you want an uncontrolled input :

```
<TextInput deafultValue={groupName}
<TextInput defaultValue={description}
```

Comment: when I try editing I get an error saying: this.props.onChangeText(value) is not a function

Comment: With which solution is this occurring ?

Comment: sorry, i was calling the wrong onChangText function

Comment: Please can you check something for me, for some funny reason, editing the description textbox doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work' and which solution did you choose ?

Comment: I did choose the second one, i'm able to edit for the group name but not the description

Comment: Well I guess I was wrong and only the first syntax is usable to create a controlled input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187753/discussion-between-developer-and-treycos).